# Why do a innocent people suffer?

Tags: practical-islam

Assalamu'alaikum, why do innocent people suffer?

JazakAllah khairan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a simple answer. Which is that: This life is a test.

And these two verses of the Quran should also answer your question.

> 67:2
>
> [He] who created death and life to test you [as to] which of you is best in deed - and He is the Exalted in Might, the Forgiving -
> — Saheeh International

> 2:155
>
> And We will surely test you with something of fear and hunger and a loss of wealth and lives and fruits, but give good tidings to the patient,
> — Saheeh International

I recommend you to watch this video if you have further doubts:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7thcLsznVYM

Comment: JazakAllah Khairan. Thank you for the answer. Yes it a test. But why the difficulties aren't equal, why some people go through more difficult test since childhood, why the weight of difficulties varies since childhood? I was just wondering.

Comment: @dailyrain Because Allah tests different people differently. And Allah is just. You won't even be able to object to His justice in the day of judgement. So if you are wronged in this world, be sure, that Allah's justice is there.

Comment: @dailyrain If you are suffering, then see [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5640) and [this website](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/32690/what-is-the-status-of-the-hadeeth-no-man-is-scratched-by-a-thorn). InshaAllah you will feel much better after this.

Comment: thank you for sharing those. So, a child who did born under a difficult parent/family shouldn't feel guilty, and can expect something better

Comment: @dailyrain Why should he feel guilty? But he should be patient, and InshaAllah Allah will reward him for his patience. And he should try to please Allah.

Comment: questioning about guilty feeling because those type of parents are narcissists most of the time, and blames their children and makes them feel guilty of everything. They may grow up with low self esteem, and self criticism, with the fear that if their sufferings are result of their faults as they never hear good words about their actions.